# Reading a JDF file

Tags: c#, .net, printing, adobe, jdf

Basically, I need a way to read a JDF file, so I can see the information it contains.

According to [this link](http://www.adobe.com/products/jdf/), JDF is based on XML, so I figure it would be pretty easy to read. But I can't find any information about how to do that.

I'm using C# and .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JDF is XML, but it's not very friendly XML. The [JDF specification doc](http://www.cip4.org/global/v3/index.php?content=/documents/jdf_specifications/intro.php) alone is over 1,200 pages! I suggest taking a look at [FluentJDF](http://fluentjdf.codeplex.com/). They just went open source a few weeks ago. The company I work for just bought some training from them and I sat through a 4 hour how-to meeting yesterday. Their solution for working with JDF is a programmers dream.

Comment: Even more tricky is that each vendor has their own spin on the JDF spec.